# Keystore configuration for calling services that call other services with different sets of certificates

Tags: java, java-8, certificate, keystore, java-security

System A consumes Service B and Service B in turn calls Service C , Service D .. Service N.System A has Service B's certificate in its KeyStore in order to access Service B.

Should System A also have Service C , Service...Service Ns certificates in its KeyStore to access Service B or is it sufficient of Service B's keystore have Service C...Service Ns certificates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary for System A to keep all the Service A .. N certificates in its key store. System A should only keep the certificate of Service B to call it and then Service B should have kept the certificate of Service C in its Keystore.